# Python indexing issue (converting MATLAB code)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert a piece of Matlab code into Python and am running into a problem.

```
t = linspace(0,1,256);
s = sin(2*pi*(2*t+5*t.^2));
h = conj(s(length(s):-1:1));
```

The above line for `h` is meant to calculate the impulse response, but my Python code:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,1,256)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*(2*t+5*t**2))

h = np.conj(s[len(s),-1,1])
```

gives me an error `IndexError: index 256 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 256`. I know that this has to do with indexing the `s` array, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that Python is zero-indexed, while MATLAB is 1-indexed. Note too that the MATLAB slice notation includes the endpoint, whereas the Python slice notation excludes the endpoint.

`s(length(s):-1:1)` is a common MATLAB idiom for reversing a vector. Python actually has a nicer syntax: `s[::-1]`. A direct translation would be `s[len(s)-1:-1:-1]`.

Also note that MATLAB `start:step:stop` corresponds to the Python `start:stop:step`; the position of the `step` argument is different.

Answer (score 1):

The `python` way to do it is even simpler:

```
In [242]:

a=np.arange(10)
print a
print a[::-1]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]
```

simply: `s[::-1]`

This was first introduced in [`python 2.3`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)